# Postgre SQL parametrized query for C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying create parametrized commad for Postgre in C#. My goal is write List of strings into DB table.

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "listItem1", "listItem2", "listItem3" };
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (item) VALUES (@ListItem);";
foreach (var item in list)
  {
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ListItem", item);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

This code will finish with listItem1 written in db table three times. I guess I need to separate Paramater name from value, but I don't know how. Could someone help? Thanks.

Comment: `AddWithValue` adds a *new* parameter on *each iteration*.

Comment: You need to add parameter to the command outside foreach loop as `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ListItem", SqlDbType.NVarchar);` and set its value inside the loop as `command.Parameters["@ListItem"].Value = item;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddWithValue` adds a *new* parapeter on *each* iteration. You should declare the parameter just *once*:

```
 List<string> list = new List<string> { 
   "listItem1", "listItem2", "listItem3" };

 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (item) VALUES (@ListItem);";

 // Declare parameter once ...
 //TODO: specify parameter's value type as a second argument
 command.Parameters.Add("@ListItem");

 foreach (var item in list) {
   // ...use many
   command.Parameters[0].Value = item;
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. The definition of new parameter require data type specification though.
`command.Parameters.Add("@Produkt", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);`